# Strange Smooth-div-scroll behaviour: a random reordering of LIs inside the scrollableArea occurs with mousescrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

When i scroll (horizontally) the content with "mousescrolling" i see strange effect:
- a strange reordering of LI that i have inside scollable Area
- the scrolling not stop when i reach the end of scrollable area

LIs have fixed width and height and are floated left to fill scrollable area.

This is my "generated" code:

```
<div class="scrollingHotSpotLeft scrollingHotSpotLeftVisible">
  </div>
  <div class="scrollingHotSpotRight scrollingHotSpotRightVisible">
  </div>
  <div class="scrollWrapper">
    <div class="scrollableArea" style="width: 1630px;">
      <ul id="divul">
        <li id="divli">
            something
        </li>
        <li id="divli">
            something
        </li>
        <li id="divli">
            something
        </li>
        <li id="divli">
            something
        </li>
        <li id="divli">
            something
        </li>
        <li id="divli">
            something
        </li>            
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this the jquery

```
jQuery("ul#divul").smoothDivScroll({
    mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
    countOnlyClass: "li#divli",
    visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always",
    manualContinuousScrolling: false,
    autoScrollingMode: ""
});
```

In this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/simbus82/r37LN/ you can see that after some scrolling i see 6 next to 1. Here i can't the reording problem that i have in my site, but it could be nice to know how to stop this "infinite" scrolling.

Thank!

Answer (score 1):

I checked a source code of smoothdivscroll jQuery plugin and there is no option to do it now. If you want you can edit the source by yourself somehow like this:

```
$.widget("thomaskahn.smoothDivScroll", {
    // Default options
    options: {
        ...
        continuousScrollingEnabled: true // By default it is true now
    },
    ...
    // line 1218
    _checkContinuousSwapRight: function () {
        var el = this.element, o = this.options;
        if (!o.continuousScrollingEnabled) return; // disable swapping
        ...
    },
    // line 1253
    _checkContinuousSwapLeft: function () {
        var el = this.element, o = this.options;
        if (!o.continuousScrollingEnabled) return; // disable swapping
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

I didn't test it, it is just draft with no warranty. Maybe you should find another carousel plugin.

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately in my case is not working... Do you have any advice on some other carousel?